# Need help calculating MoM Change in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm building out a table to get my average deal size by month and want to add a column for MoM change. The ideal final table will have: Month, AVG deal size for that month, change of average deal size from previous month. Since I'm only looking at 2015 data I should have 12 rows but instead I'm getting a row for every date I have.

```
select
to_char(cast(closedate as date),'Month') as month,
avg(amount) as average_amount,
ROUND((1-(AVG(amount) / nullif(lag(avg(amount),1) over (order by closedate),0)))*100,1) as MoM_change
from  sf.sf_opportunity
where to_char(cast(closedate as date),'YYYY') = '2015'
GROUP BY closedate
ORDER BY closedate ASC
;
```

Edit: Both "group by 1" and "group by month" do not work. Grouping by a created/assigned field like month never works in redshift. Both return the following error:

```
 ERROR: column "sf_opportunity.closedate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: try using to_char(cast(closedate as date),'Month') in group by

Comment: I have tried that and come up with this error:  ERROR: column "sf_opportunity.closedate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: i guess you need to change closedate here"ROUND((1-(AVG(amount) / nullif(lag(avg(amount),1) over (order by closedate),0)))*100,1) as" as well

Comment: over (order by closedate) to over (order by to_char(cast(closedate as date),'Month'))

Comment: @kostya still 318 lines when i do that. and also just so you know even if i simply do the query without the round part i still get too many lines... no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Instead of GROUP BY you can use WINDOW functions (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html). The syntax is easier.

Comment: Tried the following and got over 5k rows instead of 12.
`select
to_char(cast(closedate as date),'Month') as month,
avg(amount) over (order by to_char(cast(closedate as date),'Month')  ASC  rows unbounded preceding) as avg_amt
from  sf.sf_opportunity
where to_char(cast(closedate as date),'YYYY') = '2015'`

Answer (score 0):

change your group by clause to:

```
to_char(cast(closedate as date),'Month')
```

Comment: I get the error: ERROR: column "sf_opportunity.closedate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

you must put the month in the group by

```
Group by 1
```

Also you doesn't need to put asc in the order since us the diffult

Comment: Receive the following error when doing this: ERROR: column "sf_opportunity.closedate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Its becouse the order by in the windows function,  change the closedate in the lag function to to_char(cast(closedate as date),'Month').

Answer (score 0):

you should group by the value after it's calculated by the function and not the value before.

```
group by month
```

will do the job. Just as well:

```
group by 1
```

which references the first column of the results will work.

Comment: when doing group by 1 I receive the following error: `ERROR: column "sf_opportunity.closedate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`
Also in redshift you cannot group by a created field alias like "month"

Comment: the second statement is not accurate. the following query will run in any redshift instance `select count(*), table_schema as month from information_schema.tables group by month`